# Why new created project is closed immediately in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

*I created new project in react-native but app doesnt open I dont know why ?*

**I installed these npms :**

1. 2. npm i react-navigation
   3. npm i react-navigation-stack
   4. npm i react-native-gesture-handler
   5. npm i react-native-safe-area-context
   6. npm install --save @react-native-community/masked-view
   7. npm i react-native-screens

*I didn't understand problem why app doesnt  run*

**this is my package.json:**

[image]

**this is my app.js:**

[image]

Comment: it's crashing in ios or android?

Comment: How did you created your project ? Have you opened the console to read the logs?

Comment: in android @AshwithSaldanha. app havent opened even 1 time.  just  it  says:  App stopped

Comment: update your question with picture or comment error log in console. or you can remove node-module and npm install again and `cd android` then `./gradlew clean` then `cd ..` and run again

Comment: Problem appears when I install npm i react-native-safe-area-context,  npm install --save @react-native-community/masked-view, npm i react-native-screens these npms

Comment: remove `node_module` folder and `npm install` again

Comment: I did that, i did gradlew clean too. nothing happen. I could will put my package.json in edit

Comment: implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'  Did you add this 2 lines of code to your android/app/build.gradle? Here is documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/4.x/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

problem is with you `createStackNavigator`, i guess

also use `"react-navigation": "^2.18.3"`

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import Test from "./screens/test";

const navigate = createStackNavigator({
  Test: { screen: Test },
});

export default navigate;
```

Comment: I downgrade "react-native-screens"  to  "^2.0.0-beta.2", and problem solved